# SQL Server: Export to Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For some reason I cannot find Microsoft Excel in my list of Data Sources / Destinations even though Excel is installed. Why might this be?

[image]

Comment: The screen  you show is looking for the **source**, which would be your SQL Server database. You've not yet gotten to the portion that asks for a **destination**. (The clue is the text at the top, where it says  **Choose a Data Source** *Select the source from which to copy data*.)

Comment: It does not show up on either page.

Comment: You are more than likely running the 64-bit import and export wizard. Generally excel 32-bit driver is installed. Try running the 32-bit import and export wizard.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert that solved my issue. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bijan answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the 64-bit "import and export wizard". Generally excel 32-bit driver is installed. Run the 32-bit "import and export wizard" and you should see the excel source/destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Best aproach to do this is directly from excel, look at screen:
[image]
use the connection properties to specify you own query:
[image]